# Help understanding the bash code?

Tags: bash

What does this code do?

```
export user=$(who am i | sed -e 's/ .*//')
echo $user
egrep -i "^www-data" /etc/group >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    group='www-data'
else
    group='apache'
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts there, the first two lines and the rest:

```
export user=$(who am i | sed -e 's/ .*//')
echo $user
```

prints the name of the logged in user. the `$(...)` construct assigns to `user` what is the output of the command between those tokens. `who` when invoked with an two arguments returns login information on the currently logged in user (you can e.g. use syntactically correct `who am I` or something complete different like `who loves popcorn`), the output of that consists of multiple parts separated by spaces, and the `sed` command into which it is piped, cuts of everything after the first space).

```
egrep -i "^www-data" /etc/group >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    group='www-data'
else
    group='apache'
fi
```

sets `group` to `www-data` if there is a group name starting with www-data (case insensitive, i.e. `WWW-data`, `www-data-hallo`) in `/etc/group`, else `group` is set to the string `apache`. This is done by using the  `egrep` (deprecated should use `grep -E`) command to search case insensitive (`-i`) for `www-data` at the beginning of a line (`^`) in `/etc/group`. If there is a match found then `$?` (which holds the exit value of the previous command) is 0 and the `then` branch from the `if` statement is taken, otherwise the `else` branch is taken.

If you want to check if there is a group with the exact name `www-data` (case sensitive and not just starting with that sequence) you have to do `grep -e '^www-data:' /etc/group`

Comment: I'd be inclined to use `grep -qi "^www" /etc/group && group='www-data' || group='apache'`...